# "Japanese (Mozc)" does not show up as input method after clearing /var/lib/xkb

Tags: ibus, xkb, mozc

To get Japanese input, I installed Japanese language support, I installed `IBUS-MOZC` and then I could go into Settings/Region & Language/Input Source and "Japanese (Mozc)" popped up. Everything was fine and life was good.

However, when remapping the special Japanese keys on my keyboard, I got the suggestions to *clear the xkb cache*, for the remapping to work:
`sudo rm -rf /var/lib/xkb/*`

Now, the key was remapped, but some settings disappeared, including my input methods. And now I can't find "Japanese (mozc)" in the Input Source list any longer. (I just get the standard list of Japanese keyboard layouts, but they don't provide me with an input method for Japanese characters.

I've tried to reinstall Japanese language support, I've removed and reinstalled ibus-mozc, but it still doesn't show up as an input method.

How can I repair this?

Edit: This is my output from env | grep -E 'XMOD|_IM':

```
CLUTTER_IM_MODULE=xim
QT4_IM_MODULE=xim
QT_IM_MODULE=ibus
XMODIFIERS=@im=ibus
GTK_IM_MODULE=ibus
```

Comment: Did you reboot after clearing the XKB cache?

Comment: I did. I've rebooted countless times by now, trying to reinstall and then reboot.

Comment: If it is of any information, when I run Input Method Configuration, the popup still tells me "Number of valid choices: 2 (normally 1)", despite the fact that I only have 1 input method.

Comment: What, more exactly, did you do when remapping certain keys?

Comment: Can you run the command `env | grep -E 'XMOD|_IM'` and show us the output by editing your question.

Comment: When remapping, I did little else than edit `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/inet` by changing the HKTG key from "Hiragana_Katakana" to "IOS_Level3_Shift"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99446/discussion-between-zimeon-and-gunnar-hjalmarsson).